How do I define my own source for Pedantic BaseSettings
I've got a library that provides configuration information at runtime. I've implemented a a RuntimeBaseSettingsSource that extends BaseSettingsSource. How do I expose my new source so it gets pulled in by BaseSettings?

The docs layout how to do this! See Settings Management.
Basically you just implement the settings_customize_source class method:
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    numbers: List[int]

    @classmethod
    def settings_customise_sources(
        cls,
        settings_cls: Type[BaseSettings],
        init_settings: PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
        env_settings: PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
        dotenv_settings: PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
        file_secret_settings: PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
    ) -> Tuple[PydanticBaseSettingsSource, ...]:
        return init_settings, env_settings, MyRuntimeSettings(settings_cls),

